# ¿(VS CODE) Como puedo tener mas archivos de JSON Configuración o instanciar el principal?

Tags: vscode

Amigos me gustar saber si es posible o no, y como crear otro archivo de JSON de Usuario, NO de area de trabajo, y lo que pasa es que me gustaría organizar bien la configuración que tengo es bastante, sería de esta manera: un JSON para extensiones, otro para mi tema personalizado, otro para los paths, y el principal solo configuración predeterminada de vs code, y listo si sabes como hacerlo o si es instancia, porfavor si sabes, si no se puede tambien avisame si vs code no permite tener mas JSON.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo normalmente hago eso por proyecto. Puedes ver un ejemplo de configuración en mi repo de github (es para programación en Drupal 8|9); https://github.com/oscarnovasf/VSCode-settings